# Spring's @JmsListener only receiving one message from Solace queue

Tags: java, spring, queue, listener, solace

I have just configured a listener using Spring's @JmsListener, yet when I use a single method parameter, I only receive one message from my queue.

```
@JmsListener(...)
public void onMessage(Message message)
```

It doesn't behave like a traditional listener in this case - only one messaged is ever received! Not an influx of single messages one at a time as I would expect.

However, if I change the method definition to become

```
@JmsListener(...)
public void onMessage(List<Message> messages)
```

I receive all of them as a list. This has never happened before, and the only unknown in this instance is how the Solace queue is configured. Are there batch settings on the queue I may not be aware of?

Comment: Please share your Spring XML resource file and code snippet so that this can be reproduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the messages were actually being sent as a list!

As in:

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(listOfMessages);
```

It seems Spring only allows the first in this list to be accessed if you define your listener as:

```
public void onMessage(Message message){}
```